# Internet stops, can't restart it

Tags: networking, internet, 17.10, lan

After upgrading to 17.10, Internet stops working after some time (hours).  WIFI works on other devices, I believe this is the problem is with my wired LAN adapter.

I can't make it work with

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

but it starts working after suspending and waking up the computer.  I'm looking for a console command to restart the LAN adapter, and if possible for a permanent fix.

I already saw many questions related to this, but none answer this particular case.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Irrespective of the need to troubleshoot the root cause, it may work by simply using the network manager *indicator* and disconnect/connect.

Comment: @MichaelBay, thank you for the advice, I didn't mention it, it doesn't work.  It was the first thing I tried.

Comment: It seems to be related to torrent, lowering number of connections didn't help.  Local ping responds, but internet ping doesn't.  I can restart it with ifconfig down and up, but it seems too much for a specific problem.

Comment: It continues under Ubuntu 18.10, restarting with 
sudo ifconfig eth1 down && sudo ifconfig eth1 up
works, but it continues disconnecting only while downloading torrent, but no always.  Lowering number of connections or speed doesn't help.